# Is it possible to copy a Google Document to Google AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Following line creates a new Google Document:

```
DocumentApp.create('Hello, world!');
```

Is it possible to create a copy of an existing Google Document using Google AppScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app):

```
var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById('###document ID here###');
docFile.makeCopy();
```